# wamp server put online for anyone to access

Tags: apache, wamp

Hi ive been attempting to set up a wamp server so people can access it for testing
everything works correctly on my pc and i believe i have everything set up correctly but noone can connect to the site as it cant be reached

i have opened port 80 on my router and my firewall

my hosts file is as follows

```
        127.0.0.1       localhost
    ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1                   bandicam.com
127.0.0.1                   ssl.bandisoft.com
127.0.0.1                   btcGame.local
    ::1             btcGame.local
```

my httpd-vhosts.conf is as follows

```
    #
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "g:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory  "G:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName btcGame.local
    ServerAlias www.btcGame.local
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/btcgame"
    ErrorLog "logs/btcGame-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/btcGame-access.log" common
    <Directory  "/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

is there any other things i need to change in order to get my website online?

Comment: Isn't it related to the require attribute ?

Comment: is there another i need to add? or is mine wrong?

Comment: and am i right in sayingi should be giving people http://btcgame.local/ to connect? or am i being silly here?

Comment: What is your version of apache ? Also, have you defined the alias in a local dns server ? or in your hosts file ?

Comment: 2.4.18 i am running. how do i define the alias?

Comment: What does it means "none of them can connect" ? Is it a timeout or 403 error received ? Rest of the configuration looks correct to me except they should have the host alias pointing to your ip in their personnal host file.

Comment: error is site cant be reached dns server could not be found. this is also on my local netowork on a seperate pc. ok so they need to set up there host file aswell.. hmm is there a way to not require that or am i trying to do something impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other people trying to access your computer should know where to look.

Your server should then be referenced in the hosts file of their machine, except that IP should be resolvable such as

```
your.local.ip         btcGame.local
```

Comment: ok is there anyway i can do this where  they dont have to edit there host file?

Comment: Ask your local administrator to reference this alias in the DNS server. Don't forget to flush dns cache on the machine before attempting to reach this machine.

Comment: Another solution is to resolve on the ip directly if you are assigned a fixed IP.